# Restoring the last texture state in legacy OpenGL 1.x

Tags: opengl, opengl-1.x

I would like to remember a current texture state in OpenGL 1.x and later restore it. I can use `glIsEnabled` to check which texture types are active.

1. Does it make sense to have enabled more than one text type, for example, `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`?

**glGet*** function allows to get a current texture id, for example, `GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D` but to bind previous texture I also need to know appropriate target for glBindTexture.

2. How to achieve it?

Comment: How do you use `glIsEnabled` to check  `which texture types are active`?

Comment: bool texture2dEnabled = glIsEnabled(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

Comment: Do you use OpenGL 2? Because since OpenGL 3.0 `GL_TEXTURE_2D` is not a valid value for  `glIsEnabled`.

Comment: Yes, even 1.X, please see question title.

Comment: Sorry I overlook that. I update the title, question, and tags to be specific about that.

Comment: @Irbis yes it does make sense to enable more texture types... its called multi texturing and CUBE_MAPS where often used as background reflection or fast normalization for bump mapping in the old days without GLSL ...